# Customize the email widget of sharethis

Tags: javascript, url, sharethis

I am using [ShareThis](http://www.sharethis.com/) widget in my website, here trying to customize some of the functionality of the **email widget** shown below:-

[image]

Currently when you hover on this email icon, a dialog box appears:-

[image]

What i am trying to do is, making the popup disable for the icon and implement a url which takes me to a specified url let say `http://www.google.com`...

I also try to add `window.open` to the span:-

Before:-

```
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
```

After:-

```
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email' onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); return false;"></span>
```

But unfortunately my all ideas have been so far waste, their is no responce from onclick javascript? Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet works for me when I type it in the Javascript Console on the sharethis.com Website:

```
// Disable Sharethis popup
$(".st_email_large")[0].onclick = null;
// Load url instead
$(".st_email_large").click(function() { window.location.href = "http://google.com"; });
```

You need jQuery for it though.

Comment: thanks for reply, load url script is running from your code but still can see the popup appearing...

Comment: @SaurabhLP Did you put your script into `window.onload` ?

Comment: Try place the code inside $(document).ready(function() { ...code... }); not in window.onload.